# RadGrid Custom Paging while The DataSource is a List Object

Tags: c#, asp.net, radgrid

How to implement custom paging when list object is the datasource to the grid:
I have the stored procedure to retrieve data according to paging. 
The first column of  result from SP is the total number of records(here grid.VirtualItemCount = objpurchaserequisitionDetails[0].intTotalRows).
Note : In most of the fourms they are using TableAdapters. How can I implement Paging without breaking my current structure

my aspx code for grid is

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="gv_enquiry" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" OnPageIndexChanged="gv_enquiry_PageIndexChanged"
   OnPageSizeChanged="gv_enquiry_PageSizeChanged" OnItemCommand="gv_enquiry_ItemCommand">
    <PagerStyle Mode="NumericPages" />
    <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Reference" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <a class="grdlink" href='<%# String.Concat("PurchaseRequisitionDetailsView.aspx?id=",Eval("intpurchaseenquiryId")) %>'>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblreff" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("strReference") %>'></asp:Label>
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfGRNId" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("intpurchaseenquiryId") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Department" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbldeptname" runat="server" Text='<%#  Eval("strDepartmentName") %>'></asp:Label>
                    <%-- <asp:Label ID="lbl_deptid" runat="server" Text='<%#  Eval("intDepartmentId") %>'></asp:Label>--%>
                    <%-- <asp:HiddenField ID="hf_deptid" runat="server" Text='<%#  Eval("intDepartmentId") %>' />--%>
                    <%-- <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>--%>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Customer" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblcusname" runat="server" Text='<%#  Eval("strCustomername") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Requested Delivery Date" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblpurdt" runat="server" Text='<%# IMSBusinessLayer.SettingManager.ConvertDateToString(Eval("dtpurchaseDate").ToString(),Session["BranchId"].ToString()).ToShortDateString()  %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Item Type" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblstatus" runat="server" Text='<%#  Eval("strstatus") %>'></asp:Label>
                    <%--<asp:Label ID="lblitmtype" runat="server" Text='<%# (Eval("intstatus").ToString()=="1") ?"Inventory Item" : "Non-Inventory Item" %>'></asp:Label>--%>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Location" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblloc" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("strLocationName") %>'></asp:Label>
                    <%--<asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>--%>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Place Enquiry" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblclear" runat="server" Text='<%# (Eval("strstatus").ToString()=="Inventory Item") ? String.Concat(String.Concat("<a class=\"grdlink\" href=\"PurchaseEnquiry_NewLayout.aspx?ReqId=",Eval("intpurchaseenquiryId")),"\" >Place Inventory Enquiry</a>") :String.Concat(String.Concat("<a class=\"grdlink\" href=\"PurchaseEnquiry_NonInventoryItemNewLayout.aspx?ReqId=",Eval("intpurchaseenquiryId")),"\" >Place NonInventory Enquiry</a>")  %>'></asp:Label>
                    <%--     <asp:HiddenField ID="hf_statusid" runat="server" value='<%#  Eval("intstatus") %>' />--%>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_statusid" Visible="false" runat="server" Text='<%#  Eval("strstatus") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chk_Select" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chk_select_CheckedChanged" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Edit Requisition" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnEdit" ImageUrl="~/images/edit.gif" CommandName="EditPurchaseRequisition"
                        CausesValidation="false" PostBackUrl='<%# (Eval("Iscleared").ToString()=="True") ? "#": String.Concat("purchase_requisition.aspx?RequisitionId=",Eval("intpurchaseenquiryId")) %>'
                        runat="server" ToolTip="Edit PurchaseRequisition" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Print" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImgPrint" ImageUrl="~/images/printer.png" runat="server" ImageAlign="AbsMiddle"
                        ToolTip="Print Requisition" CommandName="print" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("intpurchaseenquiryId") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
        </Columns>
        <PagerTemplate>
            <asp:Panel ID="PagerPanel" Style="padding: 6px; line-height: 24px" runat="server">
                <div style="float: left">
                    <span style="margin-right: 3px;">Page size:</span>
                    <telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox1" DataSource="<%# new object[]{10, 50, 100, 250} %>"
                        Style="margin-right: 20px;" Width="40px" SelectedValue='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "Paging.PageSize") %>'
                        runat="server" OnClientSelectedIndexChanged="RadComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    </telerik:RadComboBox>
                </div>
                <div style="margin: 0px; float: right;">
                    Displaying page
                    <%# (int)DataBinder.Eval(Container, "Paging.CurrentPageIndex") + 1 %>
                    of
                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "Paging.PageCount")%>
                    , items
                    <%# (int)DataBinder.Eval(Container, "Paging.FirstIndexInPage") + 1 %>
                    to
                    <%# (int)DataBinder.Eval(Container, "Paging.LastIndexInPage") + 1 %>
                    of
                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "Paging.DataSourceCount")%>
                </div>
                <div style="width: 260px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; float: left; margin-right: 10px;
                    white-space: nowrap;">
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" EnableTheming="false" runat="server" OnClientClick="changePage('first'); return false;"
                        CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="First" Text=" " CssClass="PagerButton FirstPage" />
                    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" EnableTheming="false" OnClientClick="changePage('prev'); return false;"
                        CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Prev" Text=" " CssClass="PagerButton PrevPage" />
                    <span style="vertical-align: middle;">Page:</span>
                    <telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="RadNumericTextBox1" Width="25px" Value='<%# (int)DataBinder.Eval(Container, "Paging.CurrentPageIndex") + 1 %>'
                        runat="server">
                        <ClientEvents OnValueChanged="RadNumericTextBox1_ValueChanged" />
                        <NumberFormat DecimalDigits="0" />
                    </telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
                    <span style="vertical-align: middle;">of
                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "Paging.PageCount")%>
                    </span>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" EnableTheming="false" OnClientClick="changePage('next'); return false;"
                        CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Next" Text=" " CssClass="PagerButton NextPage" />
                    <asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" EnableTheming="false" OnClientClick="changePage('last'); return false;"
                        CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Last" Text=" " CssClass="PagerButton LastPage" />
                </div>
                <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="NumericPagerPlaceHolder" />
            </asp:Panel>
        </PagerTemplate>
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

the javascript for this grid is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tableView = null;
    function pageLoad(sender, args) {
        tableView = $find("<%= gv_enquiry.ClientID %>").get_masterTableView();
    }

    function RadComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender, args) {
        tableView.set_pageSize(sender.get_value());
    }

    function changePage(argument) {
        tableView.page(argument);
    }

    function RadNumericTextBox1_ValueChanged(sender, args) {
        tableView.page(sender.get_value());
    }
</script>
```

now the cs page for performing grid binding:

```
List<MdlPurchaseinvoice> objpurchaserequisitionDetails = new List<MdlPurchaseinvoice>();
objpurchaserequisitionDetails = PurchaseManager.GetPurchaseRequisitionMasterForGrid(item_type, dep_id, rec_to, dtfromdate, dttodate, guidCompanyBranchId,ref_no);
gv_enquiry.DataSource = objpurchaserequisitionDetails;
gv_enquiry.DataBind();

//PurchaseManager.cs
public List<MdlPurchaseinvoice> GetPurchaseRequisitionMasterForGrid(int item_type, int dep_id, int rec_to, DateTime fromdt, DateTime todate, Guid guidcompanybranchId, string ref_no, int startitem, int enditem)
{
    IDataReader datareader = null;
    List<MdlPurchaseinvoice> objpurchaseRequisitions = new List<MdlPurchaseinvoice>();
    try
    {
        SqlParameter[] objsqlparameter = new SqlParameter[9];
        objsqlparameter[0] = new SqlParameter("@item_type", SqlDbType.Int);
        objsqlparameter[0].Value = item_type;
        objsqlparameter[1] = new SqlParameter("@dep_id", SqlDbType.Int);
        objsqlparameter[1].Value = dep_id;
        objsqlparameter[2] = new SqlParameter("@rec_to", SqlDbType.Int);
        objsqlparameter[2].Value = rec_to;
        objsqlparameter[3] = new SqlParameter("@fromdt", SqlDbType.Date);
        objsqlparameter[3].Value = fromdt;
        objsqlparameter[4] = new SqlParameter("@todate", SqlDbType.Date);
        objsqlparameter[4].Value = todate;
        objsqlparameter[5] = new SqlParameter("@guidcompanybranchId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier);
        objsqlparameter[5].Value = guidcompanybranchId;
        objsqlparameter[6] = new SqlParameter("@ref_no", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        objsqlparameter[6].Value = ref_no;
        objsqlparameter[7] = new SqlParameter("@startitem", SqlDbType.Int);
        objsqlparameter[7].Value = startitem;
        objsqlparameter[8] = new SqlParameter("@enditem", SqlDbType.Int);
        objsqlparameter[8].Value = enditem;
        if (base.Transaction != null)
        {
            datareader = _helper.ExecuteReader(base.Transaction, "usp_getPurchaserequisitionMasterForGrid", objsqlparameter);
        }
        else
        {
            datareader = _helper.ExecuteReader(base.ConnectionString, "usp_getPurchaserequisitionMasterForGrid", objsqlparameter);
        }
        while (datareader.Read())
        {
            MdlPurchaseinvoice objpurchaseRequisition = new MdlPurchaseinvoice();
            if (!datareader.IsDBNull(datareader.GetOrdinal("TotatRows")))
                objpurchaseRequisition.intTotalRows = datareader.GetInt32(datareader.GetOrdinal("TotatRows"));
            if (!datareader.IsDBNull(datareader.GetOrdinal("purchase_requisition_id")))
                objpurchaseRequisition.intpurchaseenquiryId = datareader.GetInt32(datareader.GetOrdinal("purchase_requisition_id"));
            if (!datareader.IsDBNull(datareader.GetOrdinal("purchase_requisition_date")))
                objpurchaseRequisition.dtpurchaseDate = datareader.GetDateTime(datareader.GetOrdinal("purchase_requisition_date"));
            if (!datareader.IsDBNull(datareader.GetOrdinal("reference")))
                objpurchaseRequisition.strReference = datareader.GetString(datareader.GetOrdinal("reference"));
            if (!datareader.IsDBNull(datareader.GetOrdinal("company_branch_id")))
                objpurchaseRequisition.guidCompanyBranchId = datareader.GetGuid(datareader.GetOrdinal("company_branch_id"));
            if (!datareader.IsDBNull(datareader.GetOrdinal("user_id")))
                objpurchaseRequisition.guidUserId = datareader.GetGuid(datareader.GetOrdinal("user_id"));
            if (!datareader.IsDBNull(datareader.GetOrdinal("remark")))
                objpurchaseRequisition.strRemark = datareader.GetString(datareader.GetOrdinal("remark"));
            if (!datareader.IsDBNull(datareader.GetOrdinal("receiveto")))
                objpurchaseRequisition.intLocationId = datareader.GetInt32(datareader.GetOrdinal("receiveto"));
            if (!datareader.IsDBNull(datareader.GetOrdinal("requisition_type")))
                objpurchaseRequisition.intstatus = datareader.GetInt32(datareader.GetOrdinal("requisition_type"));
            if (objpurchaseRequisition.intstatus == 1)
            {
                objpurchaseRequisition.strstatus = "Inventory Item";
            }
            else
            {
                objpurchaseRequisition.strstatus = "Non-Inventory Item";
            }
            if (!datareader.IsDBNull(datareader.GetOrdinal("department_id")))
                objpurchaseRequisition.intDepartmentId = datareader.GetInt32(datareader.GetOrdinal("department_id"));
            if (!datareader.IsDBNull(datareader.GetOrdinal("location_name")))
                objpurchaseRequisition.strLocationName = datareader.GetString(datareader.GetOrdinal("location_name"));
            if (!datareader.IsDBNull(datareader.GetOrdinal("department_name")))
                objpurchaseRequisition.strDepartmentName = datareader.GetString(datareader.GetOrdinal("department_name"));
            if (!datareader.IsDBNull(datareader.GetOrdinal("customer_branch_id")))
                objpurchaseRequisition.intCustomerBranchId = datareader.GetInt32(datareader.GetOrdinal("customer_branch_id"));
            if (!datareader.IsDBNull(datareader.GetOrdinal("customer_branch_name")))
                objpurchaseRequisition.strCustomerBranchname = datareader.GetString(datareader.GetOrdinal("customer_branch_name"));
            if (!datareader.IsDBNull(datareader.GetOrdinal("customer_name")))
                objpurchaseRequisition.strCustomername = datareader.GetString(datareader.GetOrdinal("customer_name"));
            if (!datareader.IsDBNull(datareader.GetOrdinal("delivery_instructions")))
                objpurchaseRequisition.strDeliveryInstructions = datareader.GetString(datareader.GetOrdinal("delivery_instructions"));
            if (!datareader.IsDBNull(datareader.GetOrdinal("doc_required")))
                objpurchaseRequisition.strDocRequired = datareader.GetString(datareader.GetOrdinal("doc_required"));
            if (!datareader.IsDBNull(datareader.GetOrdinal("customer_id")))
                objpurchaseRequisition.intCustomerId = datareader.GetInt32(datareader.GetOrdinal("customer_id"));
            if (!datareader.IsDBNull(datareader.GetOrdinal("department_id")))
                objpurchaseRequisition.intDepartmentId = datareader.GetInt32(datareader.GetOrdinal("department_id"));
            objpurchaseRequisitions.Add(objpurchaseRequisition);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {}
    finally
    {
        if (datareader != null)
            datareader.Close();
    }
    return objpurchaseRequisitions;
}
```

and the stored procedure is

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_getPurchaserequisitionMasterForGrid] 
@item_type int,
@dep_id int,
@rec_to int,
@fromdt date,
@todate date,
@guidcompanybranchId UniqueIdentifier,
@ref_no varchar(50),
@startitem int,
@enditem int
AS
DECLARE @tbl    TABLE(
    RowNo int
    , purchase_Requisition_id int
    , purchase_Requisition_date date
    , reference varchar(50)
    , company_branch_id uniqueidentifier
    , user_id uniqueidentifier
    , remark text
    , receiveto int
    , requisition_type int
    , department_id int
    , location_name varchar(50)
    , department_name varchar(50)
    , customer_branch_id int
    , customer_branch_name varchar(50)
    , customer_name varchar(50)
    , delivery_instructions varchar(max)
    , doc_required varchar(max)
    , customer_id int)

Insert into @tbl

SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY purchase_Requisition_id DESC) AS RowNo,
               purchase_Requisition_id, 
               purchase_Requisition_date,
               reference,
               tbl_purchase_RequisitionMaster.company_branch_id, 
               user_id,
               remark, 
               receiveto,
               requisition_type,
               tbl_purchase_RequisitionMaster.department_id,
               tbl_inventory_location_master.location_name,
               tbl_department_name.department_name, 
               tbl_purchase_RequisitionMaster.customer_branch_id,
               tbl_customer_branch_master.name AS customer_branch_name,
               tbl_customer_master.name AS customer_name,
               delivery_instructions,
               doc_required,
               tbl_customer_master.customer_id
    FROM       tbl_purchase_RequisitionMaster
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_inventory_location_master
    ON tbl_inventory_location_master.location_id = tbl_purchase_RequisitionMaster.receiveto

    INNER JOIN tbl_department_name
    ON tbl_department_name.department_id = tbl_purchase_RequisitionMaster.department_id

    LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_customer_branch_master
        INNER JOIN tbl_customer_master
        ON tbl_customer_master.customer_id = tbl_customer_branch_master.customer_id
    ON tbl_customer_branch_master.customer_branch_id = tbl_purchase_RequisitionMaster.customer_branch_id

    WHERE (tbl_purchase_RequisitionMaster.company_branch_id = @guidcompanybranchId)
    AND (tbl_purchase_RequisitionMaster.department_id = (CASE WHEN @dep_id = 0 THEN tbl_purchase_RequisitionMaster.department_id ELSE @dep_id END))
    AND (tbl_purchase_RequisitionMaster.receiveto = (CASE WHEN @rec_to = 0 THEN tbl_purchase_RequisitionMaster.receiveto ELSE @rec_to END))
    AND (tbl_purchase_RequisitionMaster.purchase_requisition_date > = @fromdt)
    AND (tbl_purchase_RequisitionMaster.purchase_requisition_date <= @todate)
    AND (tbl_purchase_RequisitionMaster.requisition_type = (CASE WHEN @item_type=0 THEN tbl_purchase_RequisitionMaster.requisition_type ELSE (CASE WHEN @item_type = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) END))
    AND (tbl_purchase_RequisitionMaster.reference = (CASE WHEN @ref_no='' OR @ref_no = null THEN tbl_purchase_RequisitionMaster.reference ELSE @ref_no END))
) AS REQMASTER

DECLARE @TOTROWS int = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @tbl)

SELECT @TOTROWS AS TotatRows
    , RowNo AS RowNo
    , purchase_Requisition_id
    , purchase_Requisition_date
    , reference
    , company_branch_id
    , user_id
    , remark
    , receiveto
    , requisition_type
    , department_id
    , location_name
    , department_name
    , customer_branch_id
    , customer_branch_name
    , customer_name
    , delivery_instructions
    , doc_required
    , customer_id
FROM @tbl
WHERE RowNo > @startitem AND RowNo <= @enditem
ORDER BY  purchase_Requisition_id DESC
RETURN
```

Comment: `without breaking my current structure` ? Can you tell more detail about it ?

Comment: I mean its not possible to use table adapter and all, as i am already using list objects to bind data. Also I have 3 tier architecture